# AppMesh policy is not available

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

Trying to add policy to create `AppMesh`, but can't do it. According to [the sample](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-app-mesh-user-guide/blob/master/doc_source/iam-policy-structure.md) it should look like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "appmesh:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

But there is no such service. Do I miss something or `AppMesh` is not available yet?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is ridiculous: during preview `AppMesh` is not available in console, it's available in `cli` only.